# Error This key is already associated with an element of this collection

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on vba macros. I was trying to use a dictionary. But it is giving `error 457` with debugger pointing to `toprow.Add ActiveCell.value, val`. Can anyone please tell the issue? I even used `Cstr(activecell.value), Cstr(val)` as mentioned in one of the answer on similar issue.

```
Dim toprow As New Dictionary, Dictkey As Variant
Dim val As String

Range("A1").Activate 
i = 0
Do Until i = ColLen
    val = Chr(65 + i)
    toprow.Add ActiveCell.value, val
    i = i + 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
Loop
```

Comment: It seems that `ActiveCell.value` is not unique, i.e. there is at leasta duplicated value in the `A` column.

Comment: They are all unique in my excel

Comment: Maybe ColLen > the range in column A, in which case it tries to add multiple empty cells = "" keys?

Comment: Actually it was working fine and when I put some more code below it to operate on those values, it started giving this issue!

Comment: I'd inspect the current value of "ActiveCell.Value" when VBA gives you an error - then try to find that value in column A.  Another option is that your Range("A1") is on another workbook than the one you expect?

Comment: Do you want to add the values in the *row* or the values in the *column* to the dictionary? If it's the values in the column, you should use `ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0)` instead of `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`Add`ing keys with dictionaries is only possible when a key does not already exist. Accidentally you could entered the key before, *or* you are `watching` the key with the debug watcher, creating the key instanteneously. (= If you watch a certain key in a dictionary it gets created if it doesn't already exist).

You have to

- make sure you are not watching the key with the debugger
- create unique entries by testing on `d.Exists(keyname)` and then use the `d.Add keyname, value` method
- alternatively you can default to overwrite existing keys by using `d.Item(keyname) = value`

Answer (score 0):

You can also add some very basic error handling, if all you wish to do is skip over the record throwing this error. I simply inserted the below line immediately above the one which was generating this error for me, and now it happily moves along, ignoring duplicate keys which used to throw this error.

```
On Error Resume Next
```

Comment: How will this line help with the error *handling*? Perhaps an `On Error Goto 0` or even a `if Err.number <> 0 then` would help.

Comment: I am new to VBA so please do correct me if I'm mistaken here; my comments are based on my own testing with running my full macro across a limited data set.

All I needed was to ignore the duplicate value because I'm using a [roll-up macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25889766/ms-project-2013-display-resources-on-summary-tasks/25901025), which provides a union of values. (So, once I have a value once I don't need to do anything with it if it shows up again) 

I added the line I reference above, and my tested results were good - seems to ignore the error just fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: [bpboldin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1778734), the reason for [dakab](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2083613)'s comment is that this is not error _handling_, it is error _skipping_. Using `if err.number <> 0` and then if not a known error, with something the code can do to work around it, printing `err.number`, `err.source`, and `err.description` to screen or file would handle the error, rather than causing an unexpected halting of the script which doesn't allow for files to be closed, a log of the details of the reason for the halting, or any user-friendly error messages to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error message: "Error This key is already associated with an element of this collection". In my case, the problem was that I had this:

```
'assign values to properties
Property Let EmployeeName(Valor As String)
    m_employeename = Valor
End Property
Property Let EmployeeID(Valor As String)
    m_employeename = Valor
End Property
```

I was supposed to have this:

```
'assign values to properties
Property Let EmployeeName(Valor As String)
    m_employeename = Valor
End Property
Property Let EmployeeID(Valor As String)
    m_employeeid = Valor
End Property
```

Maybe you just have to double check your "Property Let" code to see if you are using appropriate names for those variables that are private in your class.